# I need to combine two images so they are together side by side in discord.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, discord.js

I want to make it so my bot combines two uploaded images into a single image with the uploaded images sitting side-by-side (horizontally). I have my program prompt the user to upload the first photo, then upload the second photo. After the photos are received, I want it to combine them. I tried using Jimp to composite the photos onto a larger, cropped photo but I can't have the bot send out the composited result.

```
// ------------------------------------------ front photo ------------------------------------------

        message.channel.send({embed: {color: '#ffdf20', description: 'Upload front photo'}});
        
        // waits for link message,
        await message.channel.awaitMessages(filter, {
            max: 1,
            time: 60000,
            errors: ['time']
        })
        .then(async(collected) => {
            frontphoto = collected.first().attachments.first().url;

    // ------------------------------------------ back photo ------------------------------------------

            message.channel.send({embed: {color: '#ffdf20', description: 'Upload back photo'}});
            
            // waits for link message,
            await message.channel.awaitMessages(filter, {
                max: 1,
                time: 60000,
                errors: ['time']
            })
            .then(async(collected) => {
                backphoto = collected.first().attachments.first().url;
```

This is what I tried to do with Jimp, but my program experiences a memory leak and can't post the photo. The dimensions of both uploaded photos are h:4032 and w:3024 so the final image dimensions are supposed to be h:4032 and w:6048.

```
let h, w;
let combined_photo;

Jimp.read(frontphoto).then(front => {
   Jimp.read(backphoto).then(back => {
      Jimp.read(<random image backgroun>).then(async(new_image) => {
         h = front.bitmap.height;
         w = (front.bitmap.width) * 2;

         await new_image.resize(w,h);

         console.log(new_image.bitmap.height);
         console.log(new_image.bitmap.width);

         await new_image.composite(front,0,0);
         await new_image.comspostie(back,w/2,0);

         combined_photo = new_image;
      });
   });
});
```

Comment: The [combine-image](https://www.npmjs.com/package/combine-image) module (built on top of jimp) makes it a little easier.

Comment: I ended up using the join-images plugin built from sharp because there's apparently been a lot of issues with jimp and memory leaks